# Bootstrap modal which has the width of it's image inside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the bootstrap modal to show images and I would like that the width of this modal to be the same as the image inside.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ETLGR21heowQ3tBCwXFt?p=preview) of what I have tried so far. Without any extra css the width of the `modal-dialog` is constant and equal to 600px and if we put `width:auto` it just extends the width of the modal to the maximum (that's why I have put `max-width:90%`)

Any idea to do so?

(The object tag is fine I need to use it for others reasons)

Thanks!

Comment: Include what you've tried in the question; not in an external link that has a chance of rot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default Block elements will expand to the width of their parent, setting to display:inline-block will default the width to a child element with layout

```
.modal-dialog{text-align:center;}
.modal-content{display:inline-block;}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QF2jp2KJKgAyNEz8tHQA?p=preview